# alert()/datalayer.push are different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-tag-manager

I'm not very experienced so hopefully this is an easy question for one of you. I'm using google tag manager to track any time a span element is opened or closed on a word press site(or trying to at least). This is the relevant code and the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  dataLayer.push({
            eventAction: text
             });

   var text = jQuery('span').click(function(){
     var t = jQuery(this).text();
     alert(JSON.stringify(t));
   });
</script>
```

This is triggered by any click that contains ac_title_class.

the html class im targeting follows

```
<span class="ac_title_class">
                            Purpose                         </span>
```

The problem is that this code send [object object] to google analytics instead of sending what the alert message says which is "/t/t/t/t/t/t/ Purpose /t/t/t/t/t"(that inst exactly what it says but close). I have tried countless different approaches and cant seem to figure it out. I greatly appreciate the help in advance. 
Note: "ac_title_class" is part of a plugin.

Comment: your code not seems completed please let me know what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to push the text of any clicked span element to the datalayer

Comment: It would be less error prone if you used GTMs click event handler and the built-in "Click Text" variable. In any case your code does not show how you obtain the value for the "text" variable that you push to the datalayer. Also jQuery text already returns a string, there is no need to stringify that any further.

Comment: Use Click Text built in variable mate ;)

Comment: I honestly had no idea about that but i had to write more code that it couldn't have been used for anyways. I'm a.... dumbo for not knowing that but i'm glad i spent hours accidentally learning jQuery. Thank you guys for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the data layer with your data by passing variable name and its value for eg. `dataLayer.push({'variable_name': 'variable_value'});`

For now you check my code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = jQuery('span.ac_title_class').click(function(){
    var t = jQuery(this).text();
    dataLayer.push({eventAction: t });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much. 8 hours of referencing the wrong variable and then 15 minutes to write the rest of the code i wanted to use this for.